# SpeechSynthesizer into Storyboard

Tags: c#, storyboard, speechsynthesizer

I have created a storyboard that has some moving elements/objects and I want to add a SpeechSynthesizer into a Storyboard.

Is that possible?? I am working on C#.

```
Storyboard myStoryboard=new Storyboard();

SpeechSynthesizer reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();  
reader.Speak("This is my first speech project"); /* instead of speak I want 
                                                    to add this into the storyboard
.....

myStoryboard.Children.Add(readerAnimation);
```

Or is there a way to add an audio into a storyboard?

Comment: SpeechSynthesizer i not a Framework element so you cant animate it, are you just looking for a way to animate the text on screen?

Comment: No. I want to include SpeechSynthesizer into a storyboard.

Basically I have a storyboard that includes many animations. I want to add also a SpeechSynthesizer into it.

Comment: and what do you expect to happen,even if you could add it it would do nothing, SpeechSynthesizer is just a class,

Comment: is there a way to add a speech into a storyboard?

Comment: I think there is a way to add audio to TimeLines, so I guess you could save the speech to a audio reference and add to the TimeLine.

Comment: Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use an audiofile, you can use the [`MediaTimeLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediatimeline.aspx) Class. You can then use one of the [SpeachSynthesizer's  `SetOutputToWaveFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586883.aspx) Methods to create your File.

Saving waveFile Modified from 2nd Link:

```
using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    synth.SetOutputToWaveFile(@"C:\temp\Sample.wav");
    PromptBuilder builder = new PromptBuilder();
    builder.AppendText("Hello World !");
    synth.Speak(builder);
}
```

**Xaml**

modified from First Link for playing the file

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="200">
    <StackPanel Background="Black">
        <Label Name="clickMe" Content="Click Me" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Arabic Typesetting" FontSize="20" HorizontalContentAlignment ="Center"   />
        <MediaElement Name="myMediaElement"  Width="0" Height="0" />
        <StackPanel.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.MouseDown" SourceName="clickMe">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name= "myBegin">
                        <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryBoard" SlipBehavior="Slip">
                            <MediaTimeline Source="C:\temp\Sample.wav" Storyboard.TargetName="myMediaElement" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </StackPanel.Triggers>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Be aware that once the Storyboard plays the file it will maintain a lock on it.